# What is the fastest error monad in haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

The Maybe/Either monad slows things down significantly. Does the use of some continuation monad for handling errors speeds things up? Is there such a thing as a "builtin continuation monad" or a "buitin error monad"? By builtin I mean something like ST.

**Benchmark:**

```
import Criterion.Main                                          

unsafeDiv x 0 = error "division by zero"                       
unsafeDiv x y = x `div` y                                      

safeDiv x 0 = Nothing                                          
safeDiv x y = Just (x `div` y)                                 

test1 :: Int -> [Int]                                          
test1 n = map (n `unsafeDiv`) [n,n-1..1]                       

test2 :: Int -> Maybe [Int]                                    
test2 n = mapM (n `safeDiv`) [n-1,n-2..0]                      

test3 :: Int -> Maybe [Int]                                    
test3 n = test3' Just [n-1,n-2..0]                             
  where test3' k []     = k []                                 
        test3' k (0:ns) = Nothing                              
        test3' k (n:ns) = test3' (k . (n:)) ns                 

main = defaultMain                                             
  [ bench "test1" (nf test1 100000)                            
  , bench "test2" (nf test2 100000)                            
  , bench "test3" (nf test3 100000)                            
  ]
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of how Maybe/Either slows things down significantly?  What's the context? (is it performance or development)

Comment: "The Maybe/Either monad slows things down significantly" [citation needed]

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, I thought I would get a mail notifications. I think the following [little benchmark](http://hpaste.org/54337) shows that there is a cost in using maybe or continuations. Intuitively, I would say that jumping 100 stack frames (continuations) does cost less than performing 100 tests (maybe), but there is some additional cost in using CPS obviously. That's why I was asking about builtin continuations. Or maybe I overlooked something?

Comment: Keep in mind the cost of using Maybe and Either for error handling comes from propagation of the success state though a bind. You won’t learn anything by testing a single computation in isolation.

Comment: Have you tried your benchmark with optimization? On my laptop compiling with -O2 makes test2 and test3 take ~2x the mean time of test1 which I don't think is very bad...

Comment: @glguy actually this example is a simplified use case of a stratego like combinator library in which errors can be propagated among a lot of stack frames

Comment: @Pedro yes, ~2x is nice but less would be even nicer. My question was about the most efficient one (and 2x is still a lot...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had some success with a rather horrible hand written monad that uses something like

```
newtype M r a = M { runM :: r -> (# Bool, a #) }
```

where I treat the Bool like the  Maybe constructor and in the Nothing case put an error in for 'a'. I usually use this when I have more structure (an environment e, state, logs, etc.), so I'm not sure how well it would pay off when it is this simple but the monad looks something like:

```
instance Monad (M r) where
  return a = M (\_ -> (# True, a #))
  M f >>= k = M (\r -> case f r of
    (# True, a #) -> runM (k a) r
    (# False, _ #) -> (# False, undefined #))
  fail _ = M (\_ -> (# False, undefined #))
```

This has the benefit that we don't construct any thing on the heap, just the stack.

However, you need to be careful to be strict in all the right places. It is easy to accidentally build a thunk in your state which can kill your performance.

If you are feeling daring you can smuggle an `unsafeCoerce`d error through in the 'a' slot on failure as well and extract it at the end, or you can just translate the `Bool` into a `Maybe e` but you need to be careful, because you don't want to build up a tower of unsafeCoerces defeating all the work you went through to get this far.

The effectiveness of this approach depends on how much the overhead of building and tearing down Maybe frames is vs. the mental and execution time costs of distributing the code for dealing about failure across a lot of different places in the code. Note how >>= has to effectively unwind the Failure case manually.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of answer I was looking for! Although as you notice it, it's kind of a hack (especially the fact that the invariant "not (fst p) => (snd p) is undefined" is not enforced).

Comment: Aren't `\r ->` closures and `undefined` thunks built on the heap? Or perhaps you meant that there are only O(1) of them at any given time?

Comment: The latter. The fact that it doesn't chain them or build them up and tear them immediately back down is what I was after.

Answer (score 12):

Normally using Maybe/Either should not slow things down.  However, if Maybe/Either really is your bottleneck, you can try using a CPS-based Maybe monad like in the [contstuff](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contstuff) package.  Another possibility is to use the Cont monad with escape routes.

In any case, I don't believe that Maybe and Either are the bottlenecks.  You might be using them wrong for example by forcing too much.  It is a common misbelief that all performance problems can be solved by using `seq`.

Comment: I've noticed slowdowns (see [this benchmark](http://hpaste.org/54337)) without forcing (I think, tell me if I'm wrong, maybe nf does "too much" here).

Answer (score 5):

Control.Exception provides try/catch/finally in the IO monad. Which makes them usable in the ST monad as well (assuming you are careful.) The throw equations are usable in pure code. I suspect (though I have not verified) the exception mechanism is efficient. While not the same as using a monad transformer to provide failure control flow, sometimes exceptions are the right solution.

Comment: I should try that... but as you say it's a bit annoying that it's in the IO monad. I could always hide it behind a newtype. But if it happens to be fast, it would be great that functionality was isolated in its own monad separate from IO, like ST for IORefs.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there such a thing as a "builtin continuation monad" or a "buitin error monad"?

The builtin error monad is `MonadError` from `Control.Monad.Error`, and builtin continuation monad is `MonadCont` from `Control.Monad.Cont`.

These are not actual monads but type classes. Use Hoogle or `:i Control.Monad.Error` in GHCi to look for instances.

A prominent instance of `MonadError` is `Either`.

Comment: Those are not really build in monads the way `ST` is.  The `ST` monad has compiler support, whereas the monads you mention is just regular Haskell code.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant.